# Cast to unrelated type always fails

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have an enum declared as `Result<T, NSError>`.like in Alamofire
There is a struct City that conforms to protocol Address

```
struct City: Address {
   let title:String?
}
```

After network request and mapping I get filled Result of type `Result<City,NSError>`

And the problem arises when i try to pass this result to a method with signature

`func checkResult(resul:Result<Address, NSError>)`

compiler warns me that "cannot convert value of type `Result<City,NSError>` to expected argument type `Result<Address,NSError>`"

But City conforms to Address and I'd like to be able to pass generic structs to method (because there are many Address objects, like streets, houses, etc. )
Is there a way to silence the compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your function to a generic one:

```
func checkResult<T: Address>(result: Result<T, NSError>) {
    // check
}
```